# Detecting bluetooth device “ids”

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth

OK, before I get a ton of responses. I know an app cannot toggle bluetooth on and talk to another bluetooth devices (exchanging data or otherwise). I was just wondering if the list of nearby bluetooth devices can be read. It seems that it's hidden from the GKPeerPickerController. If it's true, then does the phone have to be jailbroken? Would an app need to use private frameworks to achieve this, e.g., BluetoothManager? But, how?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot obtain a list of discovered bluetooth devices. This should be possible with private frameworks, but that's generally a bad idea due to a few reasons:

1. Your app will be rejected from the AppStore
2. Private frameworks change quickly. Like with private methods, they can change internally or get removed alltogether, rendering your application unusable. Do you really want to engage in a cat and mouse game with Apple?

If you are really going to use Private Frameworks, you'll need to `header-dump` it. If you don't know how to do that, here's a tutorial:

http://tungchingkai.blogspot.com/2008/05/class-dump-for-iphone-sdk-header-file.html

Stick with GameKit for transferring data. It's a much more reliable approach.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why iOS still prevents the list of discovered devices from being accessible? Android allows it and it doesn't seem to cause any security problem.

Comment: Apple has a very certain way of doing things. I'm not an employee so I cannot really tell why they would not allow this, but I'm sure they have their reasons. It's all about `experience` - iOS is a platform that is tightly controlled to maintain the best experience for the end user.

Answer (score 0):

GK only works with other iOS devices. For generic Bluetooth discovery, currently BluetoothManager is the only option. It is possible to turn on/off bluetooth radio, discover nearby devices, and connect to them.